# How to display comments on homepage when using Underscores (_s) Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, themes, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have my blog set up in a way so that it always shows just one post per page, and I would like to display comments under the post on the homepage (so that posts don't have to be clicked for the relevant comments to display), but I'm getting a bit lost..

Of course, I tried looking for a possible solution, but all the similar problems were 3+ years old, and using different syntax.

I found this piece of code in the `single.php` file, and thought inserting it before the `<?php endwhile; ?>` in the loop would do the trick (as most of the solutions suggested) .. but it didn't.

```
<?php
    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() ) :
        comments_template();
    endif;
?>
```

I think there needs to be something tweaked in this piece of code, but since I'm not a PHP programmer, I don't want to mess something up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following piece of code wherever you want to display your comments on a template different than single.php:

```
<?php 
global $withcomments;
$withcomments = true;
comments_template();
?>
```